# Splash memory limit (scrapy)

Tags: scrapy, splash-screen

I have splash started from docker.
I create big lua script for splash and scrapy, and then it's run i see problem:

> Lua error: error in __gc metamethod (/app/splash/lua_modules/sandbox.lua:189: script uses too much memory

How i can encrease memory for splash?

Comment: 50MB limit is max memory used for pure-Lua objects (not counting e.g. RAM consumed by a webpage, or screenshot image data); I'm considering raising this limit in future versions, and wonder when it is not enough. What's your use case, do you have an idea what consumes this memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of Splash 2.3.2, there is no a built-in way to raise these limits. Limit is hardcoded here: https://github.com/scrapinghub/splash/blob/7b6612847984fc574ebbedf9c3c750180cd93813/splash/lua_modules/sandbox.lua#L176 - you can change the value, and then rebuild Docker image by running `docker build -t splash .` from Splash source checkout, and then use this image instead of image from DockerHub.

Answer (score 1):

I solve my problem by optimizing the lua script. It turns out `splash:select("a#story-title").node.innerHTML` is much heavier than `splash:evaljs('document.getElementById("story-title").innerHTML;')`